# How do I display the deleted content from an existing form to a completely separate url, Where it displays the deleted items in django

Tags: django, crud

How do I display the deleted content from an existing form to a completely separate URL, Where it displays the deleted items in django. I've been trying to figure out how to create a separate table where it displays all the items that I've deleted

I can't figure out what I should put in my function key

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect  
from employee.forms import EmployeeForm  
from employee.models import Employee  
# Create your views here.  
def emp(request):  
    if request.method == "POST":

        form = EmployeeForm(request.POST)  
        if form.is_valid():  
            try:  
                form.save()  
                return redirect('/show')  
            except:  
                pass  
    else:  
        form = EmployeeForm()  
    return render(request,'index.html',{'form':form})  
def show(request):  
    employees = Employee.objects.all()  
    return render(request,"show.html",{'employees':employees})  
def edit(request, id):  
    employee = Employee.objects.get(id=id)  
    return render(request,'edit.html', {'employee':employee})  
def update(request, id):  
    employee = Employee.objects.get(id=id)  
    form = EmployeeForm(request.POST, instance = employee)  
    if form.is_valid():  
        form.save()  
        return redirect("/show")  enter code here
    return render(request, 'edit.html', {'employee': employee})  
def destroy(request, id):  
    employee = Employee.objects.get(id=id)  
    employee.delete()
    return redirect("/show")
```

Comment: So do you want to display all of your deleted employees on a separate URL?

Comment: YES! that's what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you want to display all of your deleted employees, then you cannot do `employee.delete()`, since this removes the record from the underlying database.

Instead think of a flag (i.e. a boolean value) that you attach to your `Employee` model - for example "deleted" with a default value `False`. Once you go into your `destroy` function you just do

```
employee.deleted =True
employee.save()
```

and in your `show` function you do the following:

```
Employee.objects.filter(deleted=False)
```

On your separate URL where you want to display all the deleted employees you do

```
Employee.objects.filter(deleted=True)
```

You can also work with [custom model managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/managers/#modifying-a-manager-s-initial-queryset) there.